# Replace string for sed \n

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to replace 
`),(` with `),\n(`:

```
sed -i.bak s/),(/),\n(/g backup.sql
```

But it causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
sed -i.bak 's/),(/),\n(/g' backup.sql
```

For using with old sed version such as on BSD (OSX):

```
sed -i.bak 's/),(/),'$'\\\n''(/g' backup.sql
```